# Are there any alternatives for NIntegrate to calculate the area for which $f(x,y)<0$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization, boolean-computation

I have this two-variable function
$$f(x,y)= (8 \cos (x+y)+7)\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos \frac{x-2 y}{2}+2 \cos \left(\frac{3 x}{2}\right) $$
where $0<x,y<\pi$. I want to calculate numerically the area for which the function is negative $f(x,y)<0$. I use this code

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[2 Cos[(3 x)/2] + Cos[1/2 (x - 2 y)] + 
    Cos[x/2] (7 + 8 Cos[x + y]) < 0], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]
```

and it gives the answer $3.49458$, but Mathematica gives the following warnings. Are there any other ways to calculate this value that is more reliable and more accurate than this method?

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 3.494581434480605 `and 0.002397336775896384` for the integral and error estimates.

Comment: Your `f[x, y]` is a constant rather than a function of `x` and `y`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, it was a typo mistake.

Comment: There is an exact solution to your integral $-2 \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(i \sqrt{3}+1\right)\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)\right)+\frac{2 \pi ^2}{9}$

Comment: @yarchik I think you should add that and its derivation as an answer.

Comment: @yarchik Could you please explain how to obtain this exact solution?

Comment: @SaraChem @Kiro I was simply a bit more patient than @eyorble. I used `u = Integrate[upperCurve, {x, 0, Pi}]` and `v = Integrate[lowerCurve, {x, 0, 2 Pi/3}]`, followed by `u-v`. The `lowerCurve` and the `upperCurve` are defined in eyorble's post.

Answer (score 4):

Let us name the function of interest `f[x,y]`:

```
f[x_, y_] := (8 Cos[x + y] + 7) Cos[x/2] + Cos[(x - 2 y)/2] + 2 Cos[3 x/2]
```

Attempt to `ContourPlot` to find the zero lines:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]
```

> [image: Contour plot of zero lines for f[x,y]]

Simple numerical evaluation determines that the negative region is the inside of these two curves. Notice that the `ContourPlot` is quite rapid and has very clean lines. Interesting coincidence. Perhaps there exists an analytical solution to these curve lines?

```
sol = Solve[{f[x, y] == 0}]
```

This returns a list of 4 possible curves, while also stating that some solutions may be missing. By manual inspection (such as by using `Plot`), we can find that the 2nd and 4th solutions are of interest to us, so we shall label them:

```
upperCurve = y /. sol[[2]];
lowerCurve = y /. sol[[4]];
Plot[{upperCurve, lowerCurve}, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, Pi}]
```

> [image: Plots of the 2nd (blue) and 4th (yellow) curves]

Checking the curves manually by plotting them against the original `ContourPlot`, we see that `upperCurve` matches the upper line for the whole domain, and that `lowerCurve` matches the lower line up until it reaches its minimum.

Find the minimum of the `lowerCurve`:

```
FindMinimum[{lowerCurve, 0 < x < Pi}, x, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

> {1.872299341324760554288429*10^-8, {x -> 2.094395111754692173633430}}

The warning about a small imaginary part is of little concern here, but you can increase the `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal` if you would like more digits.

Michael Seifert also pointed out that an exact form can be found for this solution by applying `TrigFactor` to `f[x,y]`:

```
TrigFactor[f[x,y]]
```

> 2 (Cos[x/2 - y/2] + 2 Cos[x/2 + y/2]) (2 Cos[x + y/2] + Cos[y/2]) == 0

The lower line happens to correspond to the second variable factor in this expression, and its minimum is found when `y` is set to 0 and solved.

```
Solve[{(2 Cos[x + y/2] + Cos[y/2]) == 0 /. y -> 0, 0 < x < Pi}, x]
```

> {{ x -> 2 Pi/ 3 }}

Integrate the area below the 2nd curve over the whole domain minus the area under the 4th curve for 0 through 2.094...

```
NIntegrate[upperCurve, {x, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 25] - 
 NIntegrate[lowerCurve, {x, 0, 2.09439511175469217363342977478168904781`25.},
   WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

> 3.49805583366099845069196

Or with the exact form, we can see a slightly different answer:

```
NIntegrate[upperCurve, {x, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 25] - 
 NIntegrate[lowerCurve, {x, 0, 2 Pi/3}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

> 3.49805583366099836305434

While this method is not universally applicable, it does work for this function and is much faster than `Area` or direct application of `NIntegrate` and `Boole` for high precisions. As yarchik notes, you can swap `NIntegrate` for `Integrate` here to acquire an exact solution, though it takes a bit longer to evaluate.

Comment: Using `TrigFactor` on `f[x,y]` shows that the two curves are $\cos((x-y)/2) + 2 \cos((x+y)/2) = 0$ (upper) and $2 \cos (x+y/2)+ \cos(y/2) = 0$ (lower).  I don't know if that really helps, though.

Comment: If nothing else, it shows that the intersection of the lower curve with the $x$-axis is when $2 \cos x + 1 = 0$, or $x = 2 \pi/3$.

Comment: There are a lot of inconsistencies in your answer. What is `y` that you are integrating?

Comment: @yarchik The `y` in the integration should be read as `y /. sol[[2]]` (which is the upper curve from the contour plot) or `y /. sol[[4]]` (which is the lower curve from the contour plot). These are just explicit forms (in `x`) of the curves where `f[x,y]==0`, selected to match the curves we are interested in.

Comment: @yarchik I have modified the answer to hopefully clarify what's being integrated here.

Comment: Thank you, much better now!

Comment: A note: although it takes a while to evaluate, `Integrate` can find a closed form for the final expression as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

RegionPlot[
 2 Cos[(3 x)/2] + Cos[1/2 (x - 2 y)] + Cos[x/2] (7 + 8 Cos[x + y]) < 0,
 {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[{2 Cos[(3 x)/2] + Cos[1/2 (x - 2 y)] + 
       Cos[x/2] (7 + 8 Cos[x + y]) < 0 && 0 < x < Pi && 
     0 < y < Pi}, {x, y}];

Area[rgn, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

(* 3.49805 *)

Area[rgn, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* 3.49805 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar way is

```
reg=ImplicitRegion[
   2 Cos[(3 x)/2] + Cos[1/2 (x - 2 y)] + Cos[x/2] (7 + 8 Cos[x + y]) <
     0, {{x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}}];
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

> `3.49485`

Comment: Thanks. Does WorkingPrecission matter in this method? I see a small difference in the different answers here obtained by different methods others suggested; if I need the most accurate one, which one is more reliable?

Answer (score 0):

`Method ->"LocalAdaptive"`  evaluates without errormessage

```
NIntegrate[Boole[2 Cos[(3 x)/2] + Cos[1/2 (x - 2 y)] +Cos[x/2] (7 + 8 Cos[x + y]) < 0], {x, 0, Pi}, {y,0, Pi}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
(*3.49818*)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does WorkingPrecission matter in this method? I see a small difference in the different answers here obtained by different methods others suggested; if I need the most accurate one, which one is more reliable?

Comment: @SaraChem Sorry, I was offline some days.  If you add the option `, IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors = Through[#1@"Error"]) &)` inside `NIntegrate` , it's possible to evaluate the integrationerror `Total@errors` afterwards. Might be helpful.